# List keys in DB, DBX, KEK and PK databases

Tags: secure-boot

I'm using EFI with Ubuntu and it's works ok. But I want to list what keys are in DB, DBX, KEK and PK databases? What command I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be `efi-readvar` from the *efitools* package.